# How to use .N to return other variables in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4,4,5,5),
           name=c('a','a','b','c','c','e','e'), 
           url=c('aa.com','aa1.com','bb.com','cc.com','cc.com', 'ee.com', 'ee.com'))
```

return,

```
   id name     url
1:  1    a  aa.com
2:  2    a aa1.com
3:  3    b  bb.com
4:  4    c  cc.com
5:  4    c  cc.com
6:  5    e  ee.com
7:  5    e  ee.com
```

As you can see from the `dt`, the `url` and `id` are the unique variables. The column `Name` is not unique and can be duplicates of the same data. For example, `Name` can be the same, but `url` and `id` cannot.

I would like the result as follows:

```
   id name     url N
1:  1    a  aa.com 1
2:  2    a aa1.com 1
3:  3    b  bb.com 1
4:  4    c  cc.com 2
5:  5    e  ee.com 2
```

Could you please give me suggestions?

Comment: `dt[, .(name = unique(name), id = unique(id), N = .N), by = url]`? I find your question unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% group_by(id,name,url) %>%
  summarise(N = n())

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id, name [?]
     id name  url         N
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <int>
1     1 a     aa.com      1
2     2 a     aa1.com     1
3     3 b     bb.com      1
4     4 c     cc.com      2
5     5 e     ee.com      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a workable solution: `unique(dt[,list(N=.N, id=id), by = url])`